# create a submit button with spinner

Tags: html, css

I want the spinner to be placed here as a part of the submit input button:

[image]

But I'm unable to find a proper solution, here is what I tried:

```css
/*button itself*/
.btn {
  font-family: "iransansdnlight";
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ad69f4;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 49px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 5px 0;
  margin-top: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn:not(.disabled):hover {
  background-color: #9f5ae7;
}


/*Submit Spinner*/
.submit-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

.spinner {
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}
.spinner.center {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.spinner-blade {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0.4629em;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0.074em;
  height: 0.2777em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  background-color: transparent;
  transform-origin: center -0.2222em;
  -webkit-animation: spinner-fade 1s infinite linear;
          animation: spinner-fade 1s infinite linear;
}
.spinner-blade:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
          animation-delay: 0s;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.spinner-blade:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.083s;
          animation-delay: 0.083s;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}
.spinner-blade:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.166s;
          animation-delay: 0.166s;
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}
.spinner-blade:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.249s;
          animation-delay: 0.249s;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.spinner-blade:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.332s;
          animation-delay: 0.332s;
  transform: rotate(120deg);
}
.spinner-blade:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.415s;
          animation-delay: 0.415s;
  transform: rotate(150deg);
}
.spinner-blade:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.498s;
          animation-delay: 0.498s;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.spinner-blade:nth-child(8) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.581s;
          animation-delay: 0.581s;
  transform: rotate(210deg);
}
.spinner-blade:nth-child(9) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.664s;
          animation-delay: 0.664s;
  transform: rotate(240deg);
}
.spinner-blade:nth-child(10) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.747s;
          animation-delay: 0.747s;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
.spinner-blade:nth-child(11) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.83s;
          animation-delay: 0.83s;
  transform: rotate(300deg);
}
.spinner-blade:nth-child(12) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.913s;
          animation-delay: 0.913s;
  transform: rotate(330deg);
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinner-fade {
  0% {
    background-color: #69717d;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}

@keyframes spinner-fade {
  0% {
    background-color: #69717d;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="submit-container">
              <div class="spinner center">
                <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
                <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
                <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
                <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
                <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
                <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
                <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
                <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
                <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
                <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
                <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
                <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
              </div>
              <input class="btn submit disabled" id="submit-register" type="submit" value="ثبت نام" />
            </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `position:absolute` instead of relative.

You can position it `50%` from top. And since the width/height of the spinner is known, you can use a negative top margin to give some offset based on the center of the spinner.

```css
/*button itself*/
.btn {
  font-family: "iransansdnlight";
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ad69f4;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 49px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 5px 0;
  margin-top: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn:not(.disabled):hover {
  background-color: #9f5ae7;
}


/*Submit Spinner*/
.submit-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.spinner {
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}
.spinner.center {
  left: 7.5%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.spinner-blade {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0.4629em;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0.074em;
  height: 0.2777em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  background-color: transparent;
  transform-origin: center -0.2222em;
  -webkit-animation: spinner-fade 1s infinite linear;
          animation: spinner-fade 1s infinite linear;
}
.spinner-blade:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
          animation-delay: 0s;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
.spinner-blade:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.083s;
          animation-delay: 0.083s;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}
.spinner-blade:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.166s;
          animation-delay: 0.166s;
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}
.spinner-blade:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.249s;
          animation-delay: 0.249s;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.spinner-blade:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.332s;
          animation-delay: 0.332s;
  transform: rotate(120deg);
}
.spinner-blade:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.415s;
          animation-delay: 0.415s;
  transform: rotate(150deg);
}
.spinner-blade:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.498s;
          animation-delay: 0.498s;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.spinner-blade:nth-child(8) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.581s;
          animation-delay: 0.581s;
  transform: rotate(210deg);
}
.spinner-blade:nth-child(9) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.664s;
          animation-delay: 0.664s;
  transform: rotate(240deg);
}
.spinner-blade:nth-child(10) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.747s;
          animation-delay: 0.747s;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
.spinner-blade:nth-child(11) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.83s;
          animation-delay: 0.83s;
  transform: rotate(300deg);
}
.spinner-blade:nth-child(12) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.913s;
          animation-delay: 0.913s;
  transform: rotate(330deg);
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinner-fade {
  0% {
    background-color: #69717d;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}

@keyframes spinner-fade {
  0% {
    background-color: #69717d;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="submit-container">
              <div class="spinner center">
                <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
                <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
                <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
                <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
                <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
                <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
                <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
                <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
                <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
                <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
                <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
                <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
              </div>
              <input class="btn submit disabled" id="submit-register" type="submit" value="ثبت نام" />
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have used absolute positioning, so you only need to tweak the `left` and `top` attributes of the `.spinner.center`. I also took the liberty to change the color of your blades, so they are in contrast with the background.

```css
/*button itself*/

.btn {
  font-family: "iransansdnlight";
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ad69f4;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 49px;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 5px 0;
  margin-top: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn:not(.disabled):hover {
  background-color: #9f5ae7;
}


/*Submit Spinner*/

.submit-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

.spinner {
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}

.spinner.center {
  left: 28px;
  top: 6px;
  margin: auto;
}

.spinner-blade {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0.4629em;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0.074em;
  height: 0.2777em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  background-color: transparent;
  transform-origin: center -0.2222em;
  -webkit-animation: spinner-fade 1s infinite linear;
  animation: spinner-fade 1s infinite linear;
}

.spinner-blade:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.spinner-blade:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.083s;
  animation-delay: 0.083s;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.spinner-blade:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.166s;
  animation-delay: 0.166s;
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

.spinner-blade:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.249s;
  animation-delay: 0.249s;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.spinner-blade:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.332s;
  animation-delay: 0.332s;
  transform: rotate(120deg);
}

.spinner-blade:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.415s;
  animation-delay: 0.415s;
  transform: rotate(150deg);
}

.spinner-blade:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.498s;
  animation-delay: 0.498s;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.spinner-blade:nth-child(8) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.581s;
  animation-delay: 0.581s;
  transform: rotate(210deg);
}

.spinner-blade:nth-child(9) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.664s;
  animation-delay: 0.664s;
  transform: rotate(240deg);
}

.spinner-blade:nth-child(10) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.747s;
  animation-delay: 0.747s;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.spinner-blade:nth-child(11) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.83s;
  animation-delay: 0.83s;
  transform: rotate(300deg);
}

.spinner-blade:nth-child(12) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.913s;
  animation-delay: 0.913s;
  transform: rotate(330deg);
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinner-fade {
  0% {
    background-color: white;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}

@keyframes spinner-fade {
  0% {
    background-color: white;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="submit-container">
  <div class="spinner center">
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
    <div class="spinner-blade"></div>
  </div>
  <input class="btn submit disabled" id="submit-register" type="submit" value="ثبت نام" />
</div>
```